# Creating a Login by linking login code with a java Gui

Tags: java, user-interface, authentication

I've been trying to link my login code with a java gui that i created however i've been having problems when it comes to running it.
1) The code doesn't read the text file i have created
2) When i press the login for my gui, it does nothing. I want it to check the entered Username and password with the usernames and passwords in the text file.

Please help me, I've checked for other solutions but i couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.
I don't think i linked the code right so if anyone could help with that, that would be great.

First Class:
        import java.awt.EventQueue;

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Login extends JFrame{


public JFrame frame;
public JPasswordField passwordField;
public JTextField textField;
public JButton blogin;
public JButton btnNewUser;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Login window = new Login();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Login() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setBounds(90, 114, 105, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(90, 79, 105, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setBounds(220, 82, 76, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setBounds(220, 117, 66, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
    blogin.setBounds(144, 158, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(blogin);

    JButton btnNewUser = new JButton("New User ?");
    btnNewUser.setBounds(144, 196, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewUser);


    frame.add(blogin);
    frame.add(passwordField);
    frame.add(textField);
}
Logincode lc = new Logincode();
public void actionlogin(){
    blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("Logincode.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Logincode.txt"));
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
        inpUser = textField.getText();
        String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine();
        inpPass = passwordField.getText();// gets input from user

        String user = scan.nextLine();
        String pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan

        if (inpUser.equals(user)&& inpPass.equals(pass)){
            System.out.print("your login message");
        }else {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
        }
        }
        });
        }
        }
```

And this is the second class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; // I use scanner because it's easier for me.
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Logincode{
    public static void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("Logincode.txt"));
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine(); // gets input from user

String user = scan.nextLine();
String pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan

if (inpUser.equals(user)&& inpPass.equals(pass)){
    System.out.print("your login message");
} else {
    System.out.print("your error message");
}

    }

public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        run();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}







    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there were too many errors to remember and list them all but here are a few:

One of the errors was creating a JFrame when your class already extended JFrame, essentially making it a JFrame.

You also only ever added the action listener for your login button in the `actionlogin()` method, which was never called.

There were multiple scanners pointing to the same file.

You tried to read input from the console and from the text fields then assign them to the same variable, twice.

You created a second class that has some of the same functionality as your "main" class, and both have main methods.

I left a bit of your code in so that you can see some of the errors and extra tidbits that you put in, that weren't needed. I also didn't fix your frame because there are many valuable lessons that can only be learned by trial and error when building a GUI.

Code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Login extends JFrame{

   //public JFrame frame; //Extends JFrame already so 'this' IS a frame
   public JPasswordField passwordField;
   public JTextField textField;
   public JButton blogin;
   public JButton btnNewUser;

   /**
    * Launch the application.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   Login window = new Login();
                   window.setVisible(true);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
   }

   /**
    * Create the application.
    */
   public Login() {
       initialize();
   }

   /**
    * Initialize the contents of the frame.
    */
   public void initialize() {

     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //DO NOT forget this, the instance will continue to run if not.
     setLayout(null);

     setSize(350,300); // only added so I didn't have to expand window as often

     passwordField = new JPasswordField();
     passwordField.setBounds(90, 114, 105, 22);
     add(passwordField);

     textField = new JTextField();
     textField.setBounds(90, 79, 105, 22);
     add(textField);
     textField.setColumns(10);

     JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
     lblUsername.setBounds(220, 82, 76, 16);
     add(lblUsername);

     JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
     lblPassword.setBounds(220, 117, 66, 16);
     add(lblPassword);

     JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
     blogin.setBounds(144, 158, 97, 25);
     blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //moved from actionlogin()
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            actionlogin();
         }
     });

     add(blogin);

     JButton btnNewUser = new JButton("New User ?");
     btnNewUser.setBounds(144, 196, 97, 25);
     add(btnNewUser);        

     add(blogin);
     add(passwordField);
     add(textField);
   }

   //Logincode lc = new Logincode(); Don't know why the second class was created or needed here.

   public void actionlogin(){

        //Scanner sc; not used
        Scanner scan=null;

        try {
            //sc = new Scanner(new File("Logincode.txt")); not used 
            scan = new Scanner(new File("Change to the path where your file is located ofcourse")); //make sure to add your path

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);       

        //String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
        String inpUser;
        inpUser = textField.getText();

        //String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine();
        String inpPass;
        inpPass = passwordField.getText();// gets input from user

        String user="";
        if(scan.hasNextLine()) //added to check if there is another line to read
           user = scan.nextLine();            

        String pass="";
        if(scan.hasNextLine())
           pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan

            if (inpUser.equals(user)&& inpPass.equals(pass)){
                System.out.print("your login message");
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
            }
   }       

}
```

Hope this helps.